# I wrote a function in my main view. Now, how do I call it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a function that needs to be called from several different places in my main view.  Let's call it `updateFunction`.

I declare it as such:

```
- (void)updateFunction {
    //updates some variables here
}
```

This happens immediately after `@implementation MainViewController`.

Now, I cannot figure out how to call it.  `[updateFunction];` is wrong, as it `updateFunction();`.

I know that this is stupid, but it's so basic that I don't think people are really writing about it.  Can someone please just tell me how to call the function that I've written?

Comment: Please stop and find a good beginner tutorial on the Objective-C language. There are many to be found with a little searching. This is such a basic question.

Comment: There is a big difference between function and method in objective-c. So this is a method but not a function.

Comment: @rmaddy: For a beginner, everything is hard.  Even for experts with new languages the hardest thing is usually "Hello, World!"

Comment: @par Which is exactly why the OP needs to step back and learn the basics of the Objective-C programming language.

Comment: In general, `[pointerToInstance methodName]`.  If you're inside the instance you'll be calling you can use `self` for the pointer (but you don't have to).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm in a class and under time constraints.  The class is supposed to be teaching Objective-C, but the teacher hasn't gone over it at all.  Sorry for the basic questions, but this was assigned two days ago and due over the weekend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're calling it from a method in `MainViewController` you'll probably want to call:

`[self updateFunction];`

If you're calling it from outside MainViewController then in the owning object it would look something like:

```
MainViewController *mainViewController;

mainViewController = // set it somewhere;

[mainViewController updateFunction];
```

p.s. - I recommend you start with some Objective-C tutorials.  Apple has a bunch on their website if you search for "sample code".

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Honestly, the Apple tutorials were not very helpful for me.  If you're not already inculcated into the culture, they can be very difficult to decipher.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

[self updateFunction];

Comment: self will call  for that viewcontroller.. OP want to call in another view controller...